# Illegal Instruction : 4 when running deepface

Tags: tensorflow, apple-m1, python-3.9, illegal-instruction, deepface

I have a recurring issue when running even the simplest code using deepface.
For information I run it on python 3.9, with a M1 macbook air on OS Monterey 12.0.1

I can't seem to find any information on how to resolve it, hope anyone can help !
Thank you very much in advance,
Paul

from deepface import DeepFace

result = DeepFace.verify(img1_path = "photo1.jpg", img2_path = "photo2.jpg")
obj = DeepFace.analyze(img_path = "photo1.jpg", actions = ['age', 'gender', 'race', 'emotion'])

Comment: Please can you include what issue you're facing

Comment: I get “Illegal Instruction : 4” as written the issue title. I still haven’t solved it…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution : underlying was an issue with tensor flow. I changed the version I had and replaced it with an M1-compatible version. It worked as intented

Comment: would you please share the m1-compatible version for both python and tensorflow?

Comment: For Python i use the normal 3.9.7

Comment: for tf, I followed https://caffeinedev.medium.com/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-m1-mac-8e9b91d93706